# Multithreading with the thread join

Tags: java, multithreading

I work in the multithreading problem where 2 threads are started from the main. The code is provided below,

```
package com.multi;

public class App {

    private int count = 0;

    public void doWork() {

        Thread thread1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        });

        Thread thread2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        });

        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();

        try {
            thread1.join();
            thread2.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Count is: " + count);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        App worker = new App();
        worker.doWork();
    }
}
```

In the book, it informs that there is a possibility that the count value can be printed less than `20000` in some cases. They provided some explanation but even after reading for few times, I was unable to comprehend that completely. Like there is a `try` block that `join` the threads and that meant to ensure to complete both `for` loops.

a. In which circumstances, the `count` can be printed less than the `20000` and why both of the threads won't increase the `count` value?

b. If I wrote like

```
private volatile int count = 0;
private AtomicInteger count = 0;
```

will these essentially solve the issue?

Comment: I dont see why, ¿Is thread2 supposed to do something to count?

Comment: I believe your book is wrong. Only one thread modifies `count`, and the `thread1.start()` provides a happens-before between those modifications and the println. Can you describe the explanation it gives for why `count` would ever not be 1000000? (The code itself is a bit suspicious. For instance, `count++` can't ever throw an exception, and thread2 doesn't do anything and can be optimized away.)

Comment: The code is wrong, it will not compile with nothing inside the try block for the second run() method.  So there is something wrong here.

Comment: Hello, I question was posted wrong and I'm sorry for that. I corrected it

Comment: @SeanF I corrected the question

Comment: The answer with this new code is that since you have two threads doing read/write with the same field, then yes, in many cases you will not get 1000000

Comment: @SeanF this what don't understand. Would you mind to explain it in an answer than just saying the in may cases you won't get 20000?

Comment: No, volatile does not fix it

Comment: @EJP it says the `volatile` will not solve the issue in the book for cases like this.

Comment: Volatile does help in some cases when reading/writing from same field, but not this case. Volatile will not cause the read/increment/write sequence to be done atomically.  Volatile only ensures that neither thread maintains its own copy of "count".  Without volatile, that can happen, you can literally have the two threads writing to two different fields temporarily.  But even if they do not do that, what I said in my answer can still happen, so volatile is not enough.

Comment: @SeanF `volatile` is good where there might be an issue with the caching etc. The read/write is 3 separate operation (read, increment and write) and in this case, the `volatile` won't solve the issue.

Comment: Correct, if caching is a problem, ie a thread is maintaining its own value of a field for a certain amount of time, then volatile will stop that.  But volatile is not enough here, what you need here is actually locking (ie mutex, or atomic lock, or some other synchronization mechanism)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider this sequence

```
count is 1
thread1 reads count 1 into local var x
thread2 reads count 1 into local var y
thread1 increments x to 2
thread1 writes x value 2 to count
thread2 increments y to 2
thread2 writes the y value 2 to count
```

When you do count++, it is a read from the field count, an addition of 1 to the value, and then a write of the result back to the field count, so my example sequence is essentially what can happen in your code.

In my example sequence, even though the field was incremented twice, the count is just 2, and not 3.
This happens because both threads are reading and writing from the same field at the same time.

Comment: Now, thinking back again, I don't understand how the `count` value can reach over the `10,000` as the `for` loop won't permit it in the first place?

Comment: You have two for loops incrementing 10,000 times each, so it could reach as high as 20,000, and as I've shown, it can be less, but I don't think it can be more than 20,000

Comment: ok, but like your example here is no local variable of `x and y`. It's always the `count` in the same program. Unfortunately, I still don't understand

Comment: Yes, but in effect that is how an increment works, it does a read, an add, and then a write, that is what the microprocessor does.  It's actually done in registers.  You would see it in the assembly code.

Comment: so you said the `count` in the `for` loop is somehow diff than the `count` declared initially?

Comment: I don't understand that last question.  The basic idea is that each increment is a read/add/write.  When you have two threads, then one thread can overwrite the result of the other thread because of the read/add/write pattern.